# Is python suitable for large integer and floating point computing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I am trying to play with Prime numbers.
I tried this:

```
p = 2**82_589_933 -1
p = p/7
```

And got this error:

```
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```

Also tried this:

```
A = 1.306377883863080690468614492602605712916784585156713644368053759966434053766826598821501403701197395707296960938103086882238861447816353486887133922146194353457871100331881405093575355831932648017213832361522359062218601610856679057215197976095161992952797079925631721527841237130765849112456317518426331056521535131866841550790793723859233522084218420405320517689026025793443008695290636205698968726212274997876664385157661914387728449820775905648255609150041237885247936260880466881540643744253401310736114409413765036437930126767211713103026522838661546668804874760951441079075406984172603473107746

print(A)
```

But it prints: `1.3063778838630806`

Is there a way to work with high precision floating point numbers ?

Comment: See [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/).

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? What do you want to do with the value of `p / 7`? Maybe you're looking for `p // 7` instead? The `Decimal` type is very likely _not_ the solution you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Decimal numbers, not floating point:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

> The decimal module provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal
> floating point arithmetic. It offers several advantages over the float
> datatype:
>
> Decimal “is based on a floating-point model which was designed with
> people in mind, and necessarily has a paramount guiding principle –
> computers must provide an arithmetic that works in the same way as the
> arithmetic that people learn at school.” – excerpt from the decimal
> arithmetic specification.
>
> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like
> 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as
> 3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point.
> (...)
> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a
> user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as
> large as needed for a given problem:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```